# How to detect if `struct page` is backed by a file on a filesystem in Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, mmap, dma, inode, userspace

I am writing a Linux device module that need to occasionally pin userspace memory pages. Some of these pages may be backed by a file placed on a filesystem. That happens if a userspace program which calls my driver has used `mmap()` to create non-anonymous mappings.

As described in a long series of LWN posts [1] about the issues around `get_user_pages()` and mmap'ed regions, if a driver does DMA into such pages, it may cause problems.

I want to detect such file-backed pages and treat them differently from "normal" anonymous pages (e.g. by rejecting them, issuing a warning or generally changing the control flow in my module)

Given that I have a pointer to `struct page` [2] in my possession, is there a way to detect whether it is backed by a file (inode) or not?

1. https://lwn.net/Articles/774411/
2. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/mm_types.h#L74